# message: 'Account not authorized to call twilio call Api

Tags: node.js

I am using twilio call api in Nodejs.I want that when I hit the Api,call should be made to deliver mesage set by me.But it is giving message: 'Account not authorized to call +918#########. Perhaps you need to enable some international permissions: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international',
  code: 21215

I clicked on the link above and set my geo-permission.I have checked on India.But still giving me the same error.